# Simbiology toolbox and fmincon in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, optimization, bioinformatics

Is is possible to use the model simulated in the Simbiology toolbox of Matlab
to be used to implement fmincon for the same by calling the model from Simbiology?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to simulate the SimBiology model from a MATLAB script or the command line (see sbiosimulate). This allows the simulation results to be used by any other MATLAB function as needed. I assume that in your case you want to use the simulation results to construct an objective function to use with fmincon and it is possible. Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Sure Sir. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is probably, yes. If you have access to the tools and try this, let me know and we can help further.

Comment: I have all the access. Thanks a lot. Let me try and will get back.